# Validating a link checker test

Tags: c#, jenkins, linkchecker

My group uses Jenkins to deploy our code, and I've started adding tests in Jenkins to validate our code.

In the case of a website we build and deploy, I've downloaded linkchecker.exe to my Jenkins slave and I will implement this test as another Jenkins job once I am happy it is doing what I want it to do...

The link checker in question is from here

http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/

If I run the link checker against the real url it passes...huzzah!

If I point the link checker against a bogus url it fails...huzzah!

But the actual use case I want to validate is if a subpage within the site fails to load...and I am stumped as to how to do this.

We build the website from a VS c# project and I've mucked around with it a bit but to this point I haven't caused a failure of the type I am looking for and honestly I would rather not muck with the site itself for this one case where I am trying to prove a failure condition.

So the long and the short of it:

Presuming I have full control over a client and a server, how can I make one or more subpages from a website on the server fail to load correctly on the client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do all the links point to the same host?  If not you can override DNS and point to a bogus host in the client's c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts file (if you are on windows) or /etc/hosts (on a Linux variant).

Comment: We have paired servers accessible via a load balancer. So if I point to the individual server it will stay on that host. If I point to the load balancer it will know if a server is not available.